# Remove all null values from attribute table and move all the other values to the left

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, attribute-table, null

I use `ArcGIS Pro` and have over 50 shapefiles. I used the `Union` tool to merge all the Features in one map including all the attributes.
Now I have like 10.000 Features with way too many columns.

On the Feature-row, only a couple of cells are filled. The rest of the cells under different columns are empty, because the column has attribute-values on other Feature-rows.

Is it possible, and how, to remove row-by-row all null-value cells and move all the other cells to the left? It is no problem that the cell-values doesn't correspondent with the column-titles any longer.

Comment: It would be possible to do using an ArcPy UpdateCursor but I cannot envisage a situation where I would want to do it.

Comment: Shapefiles don't actually support NULL values, and have a 4000 byte width limitation. You could do this, but don't expect a tool to be available to help, because this violates pretty much every principle of relational theory.